# Python multiprocessing pool inside a loop

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a loop and in each iteration, there are tasks that should be executed in parallel. I need to wait for the tasks to run in parallel in the current iteration and then go to the next iteration.
For example,

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
pool = Pool(mp.cpu_count())

def fun1(x):
   ....

def fun2(x):
   ....

def fun3(x):
   ....

for x in a:
  pool.map(fun1, x)
  pool.map(fun2,x)
  pool.map(fun3,x)
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
```

Is this the right way ? Or how do I achieve this ?

Comment: Do you want `fun1` to run for all `x` in `a`, then after it finishes you execute `fun2` and `fun3`? Or do you want `fun1,2,3` to run in parallel when `x=1`, then for `x=2`, and so on?

Comment: @EhabIbrahim I want fun1,2,3 to run in parallel when x=1, then for x=2, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment, you would like to run `fun1, fun2, fun3` in parallel for `x=1`, wait until they all finish, then move on to `x=2` and repeat. This can be achieved like this:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def fun1(x):
   ....

def fun2(x):
   ....

def fun3(x):
   ....

for x in a:
    # Create separate process for each function 
    p1 = mp.Process(target=fun1, args=(x))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=fun2, args=(x))
    p3 = mp.Process(target=fun3, args=(x))
    # Start all processes 
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    # Wait till they all finish and close them 
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
```

Alternatively, if you would like to run `fun1` for all `x` in `a`, the run `fun2` then `fun3`, you can use a multiprocessing pool instead:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

def fun1(x):
   ....

def fun2(x):
   ....

def fun3(x):
   ....

# Run fun1 for all values in a
pool.map(fun1, a)
# Run fun2 for all values in a
pool.map(fun2, a)
# Run fun3 for all values in a
pool.map(fun3, a)
# Close pool 
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

In the multiprocessing `pool` case, `pool.map(fun2, a)` will not run unless `pool.map(fun1, a)` finishes running. For more information on Python's `multiprocessing` module, I highly recommend reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)